# Why do statsmodels's correlation and autocorrelation functions give different results in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, statsmodels

I need to obtain the correlation between two different series A and B as well as the autocorrelations of A and B. Using the correlation functions provided by statsmodels I got different results, it's not the same to calculate the autocorrelation of A and to calculate the correlation between A and A, Why are the results different?.

Here is an example of the behavior I'm talking about:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import ccf
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import acf

#this is the data series that I want to analyze
A = np.array([np.absolute(x) for x in np.arange(-1,1.1,0.1)])

#This is the autocorrelation using statsmodels's autocorrelation function
plt.plot(acf(A, fft=True))
```

[image]

```
#This the autocorrelation using statsmodels's correlation function
plt.plot(ccf(A, A))
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two functions have different default arguments for the boolean `unbiased` argument.  To get the same result as `acf(A, fft=True)`, use `ccf(A, A, unbiased=False)`.